# Does viewport filtering affect the file size of the webpage downloaded?

Tags: responsive-design, viewport

We have been having a discussion about how web page responsiveness is quite effective in eliminating the need to do a mobile version of a website but we are wondering; yes the other elements viewed on a mobile device are hidden, does it mean that the browser downloaded only the required content or is it the whole webpage but hid the other elements from view?

Regards,
Gafes

Answer (score 0):

Responsive develpment - if done properly - should not show or hide elements between the different viewport widths, there shouldn't be any particular repetition or redundancy in the markup, it's all done from the front-ed with CSS to give these HTML elements different appearances based on the current viewport width.

That said, there is inevitably some slightly changes and additions needed in the markup itself to cater for the responsive aspects of the page (additional class names, etc), so the size of the HTML page itself will be slightly larger.

The CSS files will be larger because they contain more declarations.

In terms of actual bandwidth usage: a 'well behaved' responsive browser will only download the assets that it needs (ie: background iamges/etc within the media queries that relate directly to that device, at that time) - this is much like any browser and hidden elements: most browsers won't download the background image of a hidden element until such time as that element becomes visible on the page.

There is an exception to this: there have been reports in the past of Apple iPads downloading assets from media queries that do not relate to it, but I've not seen it discussed in over a year and cannot replicate it with the hardware we have in the office.  It's my belief that was a bug in mobile Safari which was later fixed.